# Convergence for a ratio of integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have a function $f:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}⁺$ such that $\int f(x)dx = 1$. My question: Does $$\underset{t\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}{\frac{f(1/(tx))}{f(1/t)}} = \phi(x) \leq \infty$$ exist on a dense set of points such that $\phi(x)$ is finite and positive for $x$ in some interval without further assumptions?

I am  willing to assume that $f(x)$ is ultimately monotone, i.e. it is monotone for an $x$ close enough to zero if it is necessary.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $x$ any positive real? And why write it that way? Why not say $x > 0$ and we look at

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{f(tx)}{f(t)}?$$

Comment: $x$ are numbers in a set that is dense in $(0,1)$. Your limit should be equivalent.

Comment: For clarification, I mean my $x$ can be positive reals as long as $x > 1$. Your limit should be equivalent with new $x$ s.t. 0< $x$ < 1.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(t)= e^{-1/t},$ then

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{f(xt)}{f(t)}=0$$

for all $x\in (0,1).$